# How to get single attribute value in DynamoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js

Please tell me how to get the data using Node.js. I don't know how to put one input and get one output.

Here is my code:

```
if (req.body.cityname == "" || !req.body.cityname) {
        res.json({ 
               success: false, 
               messages: messages.required 
                });
     }else{
         cityService.getCity(data, function(response) {
             res.send(response);
                console.log(response);
             for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                 res.send(response);
                 console.log(response[i].countryname);
                 console.log(response[i].tenantname);
            }
             //res.send(response[i].countryname);
            });
     }
```

Comment: Please expand your question to include more details: what you have tried, what your setup is and what is not working for you.

Comment: I tried to get the city names. But now I need to get country name with putting one city name. How to get that?